# How to store a variable in php using session

Tags: php

i want to store a value in to session using PHP

for example `$id=10` i want to store this value in a session

i tried

```
$pid= session_id($id);

echo $pid;
```

and

```
$pid = $_SESSION['$id'];
```

but not working

Comment: call `session_start()` first.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

at the top of page

```
session_start();
```

then to set `session` variable

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $someID;
```

To retrieve the value of `id`

```
$pid = $_SESSION['id'];
```

[Further more read more about session here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the right code to store the variable in PHP session:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id = 10;
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $id;
?>
```

Now to get the session data:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["user_id"];
?>
```

Also, I have write a complete guide on PHP session on one of my blog: [How to start a PHP session, store and accessing Session data?](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-start-a-php-session-store-and-accessing-session-data/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<?php
session_start();

$id = 10;  //store 10 in id variable
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;  // now, store $id i.e, 10 in  Session variable named id. 

echo $_SESSION['id'];   // now, print the Session variable
```