# Save "echo" result of a if else statement to a variable?

Tags: php

I am new to SQL and PHP. I am creating a simple program using SQL and PHP and have a question.

Is it possible to save the result of an echo statement to a variable?

For eg:

```
 <?PHP if($row["kb_articles"] <= "1"){
      echo '<div class="tg-xcve">0</div>';
}
else if ($row["kb_articles"] <= "4"){
      echo '<div class="tg-xcve">2.5</div>';  
} 
else {
      echo '<div class="tg-xcve">5</div>';
}?>
```

Is it possible for me to save the echo result of this statement (if it's 0,2.5 or 5) to a variable so i that can call that variable to get a total later to generate a scorecard?

Comment: You mean `$div = '<div class="tg-xcve">0</div>';`

Comment: I mean the result. So if "kb_articles" is "2" the result as per the if else statement would be 2.5. I want to save that result "2.5" to a variable to call it to calculate a score.

Comment: _"I want to save that result "2.5" to a variable"_... `$result = 2.5;` then?? It's a bit unclear what the issue is. I would have hoped that would be fairly straightforward - if you've been doing programming for more than about 30 minutes you'd know how to assign a variable. Sorry if that sounds harsh but I'm a bit baffled about why you're confused with this.

Comment: I mean if i run my entire code and when one of this condition is met then its supposed to echo out a number (i.e) 0,2.5,5 (as per if else statement above). I want to save that result (Condition met result which is being echoed out ) to a variable not the number in the condition per say. If i am saying it right.

Comment: Hi Guys, I figured it out. I used ob_start(); to save the result to a variable. Thanks for you response.

Comment: Ok good. No, I don't think you explained it very well unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017022/how-to-store-a-echo-result-into-a-variable-in-php