# How to stop rand() generate other integer if the page refreshed?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, just started 3 weeks ago

Now I want to try this rand() function
I want to generate  3 random integer digits

**but I don't want them to change when the page is refreshed, and it's different for each user**

ex : 987 if the user refresh the page, they stay same

How to make this possible ? Thanks !

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: You will need to start researching "sessions".  Session variables look like this: `$_SESSION`

Comment: I see, can you please give a little code how it will be ?

Comment: Here's a little something I prepared earlier...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a variable in php using session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791984/how-to-store-a-variable-in-php-using-session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save the random number to session then you can see if the value is set if the user refresh the page.

```
session_start();
//Check if the value is not set, then set a random number
if(!isset($_SESSION["rand"])) $_SESSION["rand"] = rand(0,1000);

echo $_SESSION["rand"];
```

Comment: Is this will generate different random integer for each user ?

sorry for my silly question
I'm really really new to PHP

Comment: Your question did not say it should be the same for all users, it only said 'refresh'. Maybe you should edit your question with **all** the details of your question?