# Injection sql with fiddler

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, code-injection

I have problems on my website...

When a member play a html5 game, he do a score... this score go in database with form method POST.
A member contacted me yesterday for saying that he modify my post variable and put score he want...

I juste want to know if you know an issue for block the method of my member.

ex : gamer go to
couleurs.php and play the game.
He do score.

This score is posted by the page couleurs.php to high_score.php, we say member do 200000 on score
high score post method is like that : high_score.php?save_score=200000&jeu_nom=Couleurs

My members tell me he use Fiddler to do a breakpoint on save_score=200000, he modify the score, repost with his new score and i see that on my database score game history.

````
<form method='post' action='high_score.php'>
   <input type='hidden' id='save_score' name='save_score'>
   <input type='hidden' id='tkn' name='tkn' value='".$cle_jeu."'>
   <input type='hidden' id='debut_de_jeu' name='debut_de_jeu' value='".$debut_de_jeu."'>        
   <input type='hidden' id='jeu_nom' name='jeu_nom' value='Couleurs'>        
</form>";```
````

Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Don't store the score in HTML. Store it in the session, where users can't tamper with it.

Comment: Can you send me an exemple ? @El_Vanja please

Comment: How about searching for one? Basics like these are most certainly already covered. Start with [how to store a variable in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791984/how-to-store-a-variable-in-php-using-session).