# Other ways to get user inputs on php page than html form?

Tags: php, html

So I have to do a programming task, creating a programm for primary school students to test their maths skills. You shall input difficulty level, type of calculations to practice (+ - * /) and number of questions.
After that you will be asked the number of questions you specified in you selected type of calc and your difficuktiy level.
The main problem I am facing is that whenever you hit the submit button in html form, it will allways refresh the page at the same time. I want to use rand() to create varying tasks, so whenever you press the submit button to answer a question, it will refresh, deleting all the parmeters you specified earlier and creating new randoms. This causes problems, obviously I cant use any of my parameters anymore and it wont save user inputs.
Now to the question :
Is there any way to sumbmit inputs from a html form other than the <input type:"submit"> ?
Alternativly, can you perhibit the submit to refresh, so i can use the inputs in my php code.

What i did so far :

split it up into different .php documents - this was against the task i was given, having a dynamic form, which shows your success.

tried different ways to keep submit from refreshing (window.location.reload(false)) - no changes

my code so far :

```
<html>
<body>
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method = "post">

<p> difficulty
    <select name="diff">
        <option value="1">level 1</option>      
        <option value="2">level 2</option>
        <option value="3">level 3</option>
    </select></p>
    
<p> type
    <select name="type">                        
        <option value="+">addition </option>    
        <option value="-">subtraction</option>
        <option value="*">multiplication</option>
        <option value="/">division</option>
    </select></p>
    
<p> number of questions <input name="number" value="1" ></p>

<p><input type = "submit"> <input type = "reset"> </p>  

<?php 
if(isset($_POST["diff"]) && $_POST["type"] && $_POST["number"])
{
    $diff=$_POST["diff"];
    $type=$_POST["type"];
    $number=$_POST["number"];

    $max= 0;

    if($diff=="1") {$max= 10;}
    elseif ($diff=="2") {$max = 100;}
    else {$max= 1000;}

    function add()
    {
        global $max; 
        
        
    }

    for($a=1;$a <= $number; $a++) {
        if ($type == "+") {
            echo "<br> task $a : " .add();  
        }
        elseif ($type == "-") {
            echo "<br> task $a : " .sub();  
        }
        elseif ($type == "*") {
            echo "<br> task $a : " .mul();  
        }
        elseif ($type == "/") {
            echo "<br> task $a : " .div();  
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Might be of use: [How to store a variable in php using session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791984/how-to-store-a-variable-in-php-using-session)

Comment: use `AJAX` to handle the sending / receiving of data from the PHP backend