Make a page only viewable when logged in
i need help in making my dashboard only accessible when the admin is logged in.
Hello!.. I am creating a school website to improve my html skills. I've created home page, about us, and everything that will be in a normal school website. i have created the admin login page too and stored it in (/admin) folder. when the admin enters the correct username and password, he will be redirected to (/admin/dashboard). but the problem is i can still access the dashboard without logging in by visiting (/admin/dashboard). Now how can i make the dashboard only accessible when logged in? (btw im using XAMPP Apache Server, and phpMyAdmin)
My Login Page HTML Code (in case if needed):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
      <title>Admin - Sri Swarna Vidhyashram</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../assets/images/logo.png">
</head>

<body>
      <div class="main">
            <img src="../assets/images/ssv.png" height="110"><br>
            <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                  <label for="username">Username:</label>
                  <input type="text" 
                         id="username" 
                         name="username" 
                         placeholder="Enter your Username" required>

                  <label for="password">Password:</label>
                  <input type="password"
                         id="password" 
                         name="password"
                         placeholder="Enter your Password" required>

                  <div class="wrap">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
            </form>
      </div>
</body>

</html>

And the PHP Script:
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Database connection
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "login";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully"; // Debugging message

// Retrieve username and password from the form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

echo "Username: " . $username . "<br>"; // Debugging message
echo "Password: " . $password . "<br>"; // Debugging message

// Query to check if the provided credentials are correct
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // If the user exists, display welcome message
    header("Location:dashboard.html");
} else {
    // If the user doesn't exist or the password is incorrect, show error message
    header("Location:error.html");
}

$conn->close();
?>

Thx in advance! :)

There are lots of examples of login systems online you can use. This isn't really a beginner topic as it's so easy to get it wrong. But basically once the user logged in successfully you need to store their username in the php Session. Then, convert your dashboard page into a .php file and put a php script block at the top of it which checks if that session value exists. If it doesn't, you can throw an error, or redirect them back to the login page.

Also I'm not sure whether you've been learning from your teachers or just random stuff online, but that's not how you put a SQL query together using PHP, when it includes user input. It's vulnerable to crashing due to ' characters in the input - if my name was O'Reilly for instance and I put that in my username, your query would crash because SQL would receive SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='JimO'Reilly' and of course then it thinks username value ended at O', and then the next bit it cant figure out because Reilly isn't a SQL command!

It's also vulnerable to [SQL Injection](the https://bobby-tables.com/) attacks because of the same kind of mistake. Even on a school project you should learn the right techniques and get into good habits in case you code more in the future. You must use prepared statements and parameters to make your queries secure and reliable. You can find explanation and examples of that in many places, including How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

And lastly, again for security reasons you mustn't store passwords in plain-text in the database, because they can easily be stolen by hackers - instead you need to hash the password at registration, and verify the hash at login. This means the password is stored in a format nobody can decrypt. See why I said login systems aren't really a beginner topic!? There are lots of ready-made login systems you can use and just plug into your site. You can learn the basics of PHP in many other ways

any ideas how to create and store session values?

Just the same as any other variable, mostly. You can google it easily, anyway, but here's one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31792235/5947043

In HTML pages you can't restrict users. You can always access HTML files and their content.
Instead, you should use a dashboard.php and then make the checks inside that file such as session checks.
You should create a file that helps you validate the entered details in the form.
If the user exists, then you set session to loggedin and do the check using that.
if ((isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'])) { } else {}

In your above code it will log in no matter your username or password as long as there is a record of that in the database. Instead, you should use an equal operator to check if the username and password matches the ones from the input then set the session for that specific user.
            if ($user && $password == $user['pass']) {
            //If login is correct, set session, email and redirect user
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
            $_SESSION['last_name']  = $user['last_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];

            header("Location: ../login.php?success=true");
            exit;
        }

Don't forget to use start_session() in each file you are trying to access and check for loggedin or any other session related data.

where do i need to type this code?
